# Pass data to segued controller found nil using Prepareforsegue

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following class I am segueing to.

```
class FriendsProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    var user : User!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(user.firstName)
    }
}
```

On the segueing class I did the following to pass the data

```
var friends: [User]?

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("viewFriend", sender: indexPath)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController
    if let friendsProfileVC = destinationVC as? FriendsProfileViewController{
        if let indexPath = sender as? NSIndexPath{
            print(indexPath.row)
            friendsProfileVC.user = friends?[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

Why is it that I am getting the error

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

even though my `friend?[indexPath.row]` is verified to contain a value when I segue?.

Comment: Have you debug it? if yes, what's happening?

Comment: on which line you are facing the crash from your given code ?? and your is initialised or it's empty ??

Comment: Are you getting console output for line `print(indexPath.row)`?

Comment: it means your are passing nil value of user. you should take optional value of User or you should make sure that you are not passing nil value.

Comment: Check if `friends` is `nil`

Comment: `Optional([Appname.User, Appname.User, Appname.User, Appname.User, Appname.User, Appname.User])` was the output for `print(friends)`. And yes. I do get output for `indexpath.row`

Comment: What is the output of `friends` and `indexPath.row` in `prepareForSegue`?

Comment: `friends` is as above. `indexPath.row` is `3`. It's all within the index bound

Comment: Please add your User model to the question. Also along with `indexPath.row`, print out `friends?[indexPath.row]` in `prepareForSegue` and report the result.

Comment: `print[friends?[indexPath.row]` returns an Optional User `Optional(Appname.User)` which is probably not I wanted. I have since changed it to `friends![indexPath.row]`. But when I debugged the value of `friendsProfileVC.user` it is being set as user nil

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the user before performing the segue and pass it as the segue sender.

```
var friends: [User]?

private func friend(at index: Int) -> User? {

    return friends.flatMap { $0.indicies.contains(index) ? $0[index] : nil }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let friend = friend(at: indexPath.row) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("viewFriend", sender: friend)
    } else {
        print("Invalid index: \(indexPath.row)")
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    switch (segue.destinationViewController, sender) {
    case (let controller as FriendsProfileViewController, let user as User):
        controller.user = user
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue I believe is that we always get back an Optional from array as such `friends![indexPath.row]` returned an `Optional(User)`.

I ended up passing the an Optional User as the sender. Unwrap it and set it to my other VC.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("viewFriend", sender: friends![indexPath.row])
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    print(sender)
    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController
    if let friendsProfileVC = destinationVC as? FriendsProfileViewController{
        if let friend = sender as? User{
            print(friend)
            print(friend.firstName)
            friendsProfileVC.user = friend
        }
    }
}
```

Update, I have tried changing `friendsProfileVC.user = friends?[indexPath.row]`  to `friendsProfileVC.user = friends![indexPath.row]` and it worked. Not sure why did it not work earlier on.